# Showing data in a table for an android app

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to make an android app with a MySQL backend database. For part of my app I want the user to be able to view data from the database as part of a table.

However the table layout isn't very good because it doesn't have borders.

Does anyone know of a better way to show data in a table, or will I just have to suck it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify borders for table layout using this workaround http://sdroid.blogspot.ru/2011/01/border-in-tablelayout.html?m=1